# Navigate from inner navigator to outer navigator generate extra screen slide

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a problem during the logout in my react native app. I set many navigators to handle multiple navigation flow, but when I try to logout from the app, the login screen appears two times.

I try to explain how I organize my navigators below:

I created a TabNavigator which handle the main navigation of the app if a user is logged in otherwise I show the LoginNavigator which handle login, registration and password forgot screens.
I use a state, stored on redux for handling the login state (`isLoggedIn`).

```
<NavigationContainer>
  {isLoggedIn ? <TabNavigator/> : <LoginNavigator/>}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Into the `TabNavigator` I set other navigator for handling page flow in each sections, like the exemple below:

```
TabNavigator
  Screen X
  Navigator1
     Screen A
     Screen B
  Navigator2
     Screen C
     Screen D
  Screen Y
```

Into the `Screen C` I'd like to logout from the app, so I call an action which set the `isLoggedIn` state to ***false***.
What happens is that the Login screen (the inital screen of `LoginNavigator`) appears, but it suddently slides off and another Login screen appears.

It happens only from nested screen, instead if I try to logout from `Screen X` or `Screen Y` it works perfectly fine.

Does anyone encounter this problem? How can I solve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this behaviour!
Instead of showing the correct navigator using a ternary operation, base on redux state, I wrap `TabNavigator` and `LoginNavigator` inside a custom stack navigator with a `WaitingScreen`.
I set the `WaitingScreen` as inital route and I moved the logic about which route between `MainNavigator` and `LoginNavigator` has to be shown inside `WaitingScreen`, in a `useLayouEffect` with `isLoggedIn` as dependecy.

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={NavConst.LOADING}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          contentStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Color.primary600,
          },
          animation: "none",
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name={NavConst.LOADING} component={WaitingScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name={NavConst.LOGIN_NAV} component={LoginNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name={NavConst.MAIN_NAV} component={MainNavigator} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

and inside the WaitingScreen:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    isLoggedIn
      ? navigation.navigate(NavConst.MAIN_NAV);
      : navigation.navigate(NavConst.LOGIN_NAV);
  }, [isLoggedIn]);
```